# NullPointerException with proguard

Tags: android, obfuscation, admob, proguard, adview

I'm using Proguard with my apps and I'm getting `NullPointerExceptions` sent to my Developer Console for random users.  When I do a ReTrace, it seems to be an issue with the `AdView` I'm using.  The confusing thing is, the error is happening in my `Service` which, obviously, doesn't use ads.  Not sure if `Proguard` is doing something to the code or what.  This is the de-obfuscated stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.ads.internal.AdWebView$1.a(Unknown Source)
at com.app.base.MainService.onHandleIntent(Unknown Source)
at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

`MainService` is my service, which is then showing, from what I can tell, a `NullPointerException` related to `com.google.ads.internal.AdView`.

I recently realized I wasn't calling `destroy()` on my AdView, so I added this to the `Activities` that are using it:

```
 @Override
 public void onDestroy() 
 {
    if (adView != null)
      adView.destroy();

    super.onDestroy();
  }
```

Not sure if that would cause the issue.

This is my `proguard.cfg` file:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-libraryjars C:\Workspace\JARs\GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.0.0.jar
-libraryjars C:\Workspace\JARs\android-support-v4.jar

-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-dontwarn **CompatHoneycomb
-dontwarn **CompatHoneycombMR2
-dontwarn **CompatCreatorHoneycombMR2

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment

-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep class com.app.base.KeywordsFragment
-keep class com.app.base.ListingFragment

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

# This will avoid all the onClick listeners referenced from XML Layouts from being removed
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity { 
       public void *(android.view.View); 
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-dontwarn android.support.**
```

**UPDATE:**

After looking at the Proguard manual, I found this is in the troubleshooting section:

"MissingResourceException or NullPointerException
    Your processed code may be unable to find some resource files. ProGuard simply copies resource files over from the input jars to the output jars."

Wonder if I need to use `keepdirectories`

**UPDATE 2:**

I'm wondering if adding this will fix my issue.  I can't test this though because I am unable to recreate the error myself.  It is only happening for random users:

```
 -keep class com.google.ads.** {*;}
```

**UPDATE 3:**

After retracing other errors I'm getting in the Developer Console, they all seem to be related to com.google.ads, eg:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.google.ads.InterstitialAd.a(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using the following should work:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.google.ads.**
```

The annotation piece may be in there already.  I think the issue is that the SDK  has it's own proguard, and relies on it's public classes to not be proguarded by the developer.

Answer (score 0):

The second proguard statement should be:

```
-keep public class com.google.ads.** {*;}
```

without `{*;}` it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I spent an evening figuring out that introspection can cause a NullPointerException with proguard. In retrospect it is obvious.

For example, I had to remove the line:

```
Log.i(TAG, new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName());
```